С какой C++ библиотекой писать кроссплатформенный сетевой код и под линукс, и под windows?
Я долгое время имел опыт с сетевым программированием на c++ под Linux.
Но когда захотел это же сделать под Windows, я ужаснулся очень неудобной библиотеке winsock.h. Нужно подключать как-то wsock32.lib, очень неудобно если хочешь кроссплатформенность. Мне показалось, что winsock.h жалкое подобие сокетам в линуксе.
Есть ли какие-то кроссплатформенные решения этой проблемой? Я хотел бы узнать о удобных библиотеках или каком нибудь костыле, который позволяет писать кроссплатформенный сетевой код и под линукс, и под windows.

Столкнувшись лет 15 назад с точно такой же ситуацией я просто отказался от программирования в винде

Помотрите boost asio. В winsock ничего плохого нет, дает те же возможности, что и Linux sockets.

"Нужно подключать как-то wsock32.lib, очень неудобно если хочешь кроссплатформенность." А в чем неудобство-то? Добавить флаг компилятора?

"winsock.h" не библиотека, а заголовочный файл.  Подключение wsock32.lib в явном виде проще, чем неявное подключение подбитой к компилятору рантайм библиотеки, как то обычно происходит на линуксоподобных системах. Странно говорить о кроссплатформенности при использовании системного  SDK. Тем более, что кроссплатформенности вообще-то не наблюдается и между разными вариантами не-windows систем. Фактически единственным ориентиром может служить спецификация POSIX. Ну а для кросс-платформенной разработки используйте вышеупомянутый boost.asio.
